# Get data created only by logged in user

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm starting the adventure with Node.js and wondering what is the approach to the problem of downloading data created by a logged in user.
I have a token with user id already and now what?
I thought that with api I would return the user id and save it after logging in to localstorage and then add userId when saving data to the database.
Is this a good solution or is it solved differently?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const eventSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    date: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('event', eventSchema, 'events');


function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  if ( !req.headers.authorization ) {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request');
  }
  const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  if ( token === 'null' ) {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request');
  }
  const payload = jwt.verify(token, 'secretKey');
  // verify decode jwt token if is valid
  if ( !payload ) {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request');
  }
  req.userId = payload.subject;
  next();
}
```

Comment: Can you show your 'data' schema? I guess you have authentication implemented since you mention the existence of a token, so it will be helpful if you can show that middleware as well.

Comment: First of all, welcome to the NodeJS world, it is quite nice! I have started myself some months ago. Indeed, please, send us more details. I have myself tried to answer questions with little detail, and it can be dead-end.

Comment: @JorgePires I added my some code.

Answer (score 0):

I still may need more information, nonetheless, let me try to help with what I have so far.

" I thought that with api I would return the user id and save it after logging in to localstorage " it depends on the approach you are using, say you are using just Express, Mongo, in that case, you may save, as you are doing with `req.userId`, you can access this information anytime you please. Other approaches could be sending the token from the front end (e.g., Angular).

"add userId when saving data to the database." if I understood correctly, yes, it is correct. You are using `req.userId` to store this id, and use it to make sure the current user is loggedin *before accessing the dataset*.

" Is this a good solution" if it is working, yep, it is valid.

"is it solved differently?" yes, you can keep the key in the front end, say using Angular, and send it whenever you need to access the dataset.

Remember that API in NodeJS are stateless: you do not keep information from the user, just a token, as it seems you are doing.

Your code seems okay, **what is the problem?**

*Some questions I have:*

- "downloading data created by a logged in user." can you be more specific, which type of data?
- what is the problem? are you getting errors?

**Curiosity**

It is not clear to me if you doing this, but one nice way to use mongoose well is something like this:

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    const eventSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        description: String,
        date: String
    });

    eventSchema.methods.verifyToken= function (req, res, next) {//now you can call this method externally, like you call an mongoose function such as schema.findone
      if ( !req.headers.authorization ) {
        return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request');
      }
      const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
      if ( token === 'null' ) {
        return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request');
      }
      const payload = jwt.verify(token, 'secretKey');
      // verify decode jwt token if is valid
      if ( !payload ) {
        return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request');
      }
      req.userId = payload.subject;
      next();
    }

    module.exports = mongoose.model('event', eventSchema, 'events');
```

Comment: "downloading data created by a logged in user." can you be more specific, which type of data?  I would like to get all e.g cars added by logged in user

Comment: Hey there, I really want to help, but what you are asking seem quite broad, it is not hard to do, but require much more than we usually offer here. It would be easier for you to find a tutorial, there are plenty of them. What I can do is offering you suggestions, but you will still need to code them. E.g., if you want all the cars created by a logged in user, you must visit all cars documents, and take those that were created by the user, or modify your schema, there is no place for that in your schema.